# How to write and read from a file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am newbie! On online courses, this is such a task) I gave the right to create directories to the user and created the directory.

```
create or replace directory files_one as 'C:/oracle18c/app/oracle/product/18.2.0/files_one';
```

How to write a procedure that will record the name of the department and the amount of salary for this department in a file. And separately, a procedure that reads data from this file and displays through dbms_output.
It turns out a procedure that writes data from this code to a file

```
 select  d.department_name, sum(e.salary)
  from employees e, departments d 
  where  d.DEPARTMENT_ID=e.DEPARTMENT_ID
  group by d.department_name;
```

```
create or replace procedure emp_deps as 
  cursor depts_emp is 
    select  d.department_name, sum(e.salary)
    from employees e, departments d 
    where  d.DEPARTMENT_ID=e.DEPARTMENT_ID
    group by d.department_name; 

  fHandl UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
  begin 
    fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('/C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/files_one','A');
    for cur_rec in depts_emp loop
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, cur_rec.d.department_name||','||cur_rec. sum(e.salary));
    end loop;
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);

   EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
    RAISE;
END;
```

```
department_id department_name  
------------- ---------------- 
10            Administration   
20            Marketing        
30            Purchasing       
40            Human Resources  
50            Shipping
...
270           Payroll
```

```
employee_id   last_name  salary departments_id
------------- ---------- ------ --------------
100           King       24000  90  
101           Kochhar    17000  90  
102           De Haan    17000  90  
103           Hunold     9000   60  
104           Ernst      6000   60 
...
206           William    8300   110
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give directory name in `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` method as follows:

```
fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('FILES_ONE', -- directory name
                          'files_one.txt', -- file name that you want to create or append data to
                          'A'); -- mode of writing
```

To read data from the file, You need to use the `SqlLoader` or `External table`. You can read about it from the oracle documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The FOPEN procedure needs a directory *database object* as input, not the physical OS directory path. You also need to make sure that the owner of the procedure has read/write access to the directory object:

```
create or replace directory files_one as 'C:/oracle18c/app/oracle/product/18.2.0/files_one';
grant read, write on directory files_one to your_proc_owner;

create or replace procedure your_proc_owner.emp_deps as 
  cursor depts_emp is 
    select  d.department_name, sum(e.salary)
    from employees e, departments d 
    where  d.DEPARTMENT_ID=e.DEPARTMENT_ID
    group by d.department_name; 

  fHandl UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
  begin 
    fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('FILES_ONE','files_one.txt','A');
    for cur_rec in depts_emp loop
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fHandle, cur_rec.d.department_name||','||cur_rec. sum(e.salary));
    end loop;
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);

   EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fHandle);
    RAISE;
END;
```